# Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation - cant find where I went wrong

Tags: c, initialization, valgrind

```
int main(){

char *input = NULL;
char *line[2048];
size_t inputChars = 0;
size_t bufferSize = 0;

char *command = NULL;
char *arguments[2048];

printf(":");
fflush(stdout);


while((inputChars = getline(&input , &bufferSize , stdin)) > 0){

    memset(line, '\0' , (sizeof *line * sizeof line[0]) );
    memset(arguments, '\0' , (sizeof *arguments * sizeof arguments[0]));

    if(inputChars == -1){

        clearerr(stdin);
    }
    else{
        parseLine(input,line);

        command = line[0];

        int i = 0;
        int j = 1;

        while(line[j] != NULL)
        {
            arguments[i] = line[j];
            i++;
            j++;
        }

        if((*line[0] != '#') && (*line[0] != '\n'))
        {
            runCommand(command,arguments);
        }


        printf(":");
        fflush(stdout);

    }

    input = NULL;
  }
}
int isBackground(char* args[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    while (args[i] != NULL)
    {
        pos++;
        i++;
    }
    if (*args[pos - 1] == '&')
    {
        background++;
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

void runCommand(char* cmd, char* args[])
{
    printCommandLine(cmd, args);

    if (isBackground(args))
    {
        printf("Background Processes: %i\n",background);

    }
}

void printCommandLine(char* cmd, char* args[])
{

    printf("Command: %s\n",cmd);

    printf("Arguments:\n");

    int i = 0;

    while (args[i] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",args[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Valigrind Results:

[image: Valgrind Results]

xcode output:

[image: xcode output]

I cant find where I'm going wrong here. Im writing some simple code for a command line that can accept a command with a list of arguments. The program runs fine for string arrays of length <= 7 and after the first input of a command of this size works for every command array. I cant figure out where I'm using uninitialized values. When the code breaks I get bad access when looping over my arguments array. I suspect it may have something to do with the while loop in main that fills the arguments array but I may be wrong. Really stuck on this. Thank you for your help or advise if you have any ideas.

Comment: Given that `inputChars` is of type `size_t` (an unsigned type), the test `if(inputChars == -1){` is pretty peculiar.  And the assignment in the loop control `while((inputChars = getline(&input , &bufferSize , stdin)) > 0){` is consequently dubious too.  The result from `getline()` is a `ssize_t`, (two s's) not a `size_t` (one s).  It means your EOF detection is shot to pieces.

Comment: `memset(line, '\0' , (sizeof *line * sizeof line[0]) );` is odd.  Perhaps `memset(line, 0 , sizeof line);`

Comment: Same goes for `sizeof *arguments * sizeof arguments[0]` . That's wrong as well.

Comment: You should compile and link your code with the `-g` option to get line number information in the Valgrind output.  You should also include the text of the Valgrind output instead of images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
memset(arguments, '\0' , (sizeof *arguments * sizeof arguments[0]))
```

This is the issue with your code causing the uninitialized value.

`*arguments` is the same as `arguments[0]`. And `sizeof` both is `sizeof(char*)`.

Which means you are initializing only few entries in the buffer.

You need

```
memset(arguments, '\0', sizeof(arguments));
```

Same goes for the previous line

```
memset(line, '\0', sizeof(line));
```